# virtual host alias for multiple laravel applications on single domain

Tags: php, apache, laravel, alias, virtualhost

I want my domain to run two separate laravel applications depending the url

for instance

`domain.com`  to `/home/sites/1`

`domain.com/account`  to `/home/sites/2`

I have this working, however the laravel instance running on site 2 thinks `domain.com/account` is the homepage.

When i goto `domain.com/account` i see the homepage of site 2 - not the route for setup for `/account`.

here is my vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    UseCanonicalName Off
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/1/public/
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/sites/1/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /account/ /home/sites/2/public/

    <Directory /home/sites/2/public/>
         Require all granted
         Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
         RewriteEngine On
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: it would be better to use Laravel router for different domains with the same document root.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your custom apache virtualhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin xx@xxx.com
        ServerName xxx.com
        DocumentRoot /path/to/site1/public

        Alias /account /path/to/site2/public

        <Directory /path/to/site1/>
           AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Now you need to change .htaccess file of public folder of the alias -

add **RewriteBase /directory_name_of_site2/** right after the **RewriteEngine On** in .htacess file

you can add as many aliases you want just remember to modify the .htaceess file of every projects